# Crystal Reports 11 "Field name is not known" error after adding more subreports

Tags: visual-c++, crystal-reports

I am honestly at a loss here. I have a Crystal 11 Report that I want to update, with C++ as the code base. I only added some extra subreports and followed the same style as the previous ones, but now the report fails at a function that exports it and I get this error:

`IDispatch error #29134 : Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer : This field name is not known.`

If someone could please tell me why I'm getting this and what I could have done to cause it, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

guess there is a formula or a field which should not be present in the subreports, check the fields and formulas carefully, this kind of error can be a mess, double check on your formulas and fields on the subreports, make sure that they all are getting data and preview mode is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a formula for an OLE object checkmark that was supposed to be hidden except when a boolean field was "True". I had copied it from a similar subreport that used a different .ttx file, so it was trying to refer to a boolean field from a different .ttx file.